# What to use "I" or "me" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Context:

There are 3 members in my family that is I, my father, and my mother.
               OR
There are 3 members in my family that is me, my father, and my mother.

Answer (score 2):

> The two personal pronouns I and me are often used wrongly, usually in
> sentences in which I is being used with another noun. Here are some
> tips to help you get it right:
>
> - Use the pronoun I, along with other subjective pronouns such as we, he, she, you, and they, when the pronoun is the subject of a verb:
>
> He went to bed.
>
> We waited for the bus.
>
> Clare and I are going for a coffee.
>
> In the last example, the pronoun I, together with the proper noun
> Clare, forms the subject of the sentence, so you need to use I rather
> than me.
>
> - Use the pronoun me, along with other objective pronouns such as us, him, her, you, and them, when the pronoun is the object of a verb:
>
> Danny thanked them.
>
> The dog followed John and me to the door.
>
> - Use the pronoun me, along with other objective pronouns such as us, him, her, you, and them, when the pronoun is the object of a
>   preposition:
>
> Rose spent the day with Jake and me.
>
> Me, together with Jake, forms the object of the preposition with, so
> you need to use the pronoun me rather than the pronoun I.
>
> - An easy way of making sure you’ve chosen the right pronoun is to see whether the sentence reads properly if you remove the additional
>   pronoun like in your sentence:
>   If you don't know whether to say I or me just remove my mother, my father:
>   There is one member in my family that is only me

> **Use**
> I am going for a coffee.
> Rose and I went for a coffee.
> The dog followed me.
> Rose spent the day with me.
>
> **Don't use**
> Me am going for a coffee.
> Rose and me went for a coffee.
> The dog followed I.
> Rose spent the day with I.

[Oxford dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823040749/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/i-or-me)

Regarding your sentence use:
There are 3 members in my family that is me, my father, and my mother.
Or
There are 3 members in my family that is my father, my mother and me.

Because if you use:
There is one member in my family that is only me
Or if you write the sentence like the following:
My family consists of my mother, my father, and me

Comment: and if you are having trouble, make yourself the subject. I am going for coffee. 'Me' won't work. Rose and I are going -- 'me' is going -- nope. The dog followed me -- dog followed 'I' -- nope.